# What does tunnelRemoteAddress in NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings do?

Tags: ios

I'm wring a small packet tunnel using `NETunnelPacketProvider`. Before starting VPN, I need to use `setTunnelNetworkSettings` in order to provide connected VPN settings. In this settings, I need to provide `tunnelRemoteAddress` for `NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings`. I have noticed that this address is shown when VPN is in connected status. But I wonder if there is any other effect too or not?

Since I want ability to change my connected VPN server(e.g. changing to another server when disconnecting from one) and I were not able to change this value by using `setTunnelNetworkSettings` again while VPN is connected, I was wondering if this `tunnelRemoteAddress` is just some string for representing in UI and I can set it to just a dummy address like `127.0.0.1` or not.

Any idea?

Comment: did you get the answer?

Comment: @user1068810 I just set `tunnelRemoteAddress` to `127.0.0.1` and did not change it for reconnecting to different server. It seems it works if you use a similar approach.

Comment: Thanks for replying, one more thing i have created a tunnel using NETunnelPacketProvider and VPN shows connected but now my Phone's network is not working and also i tried to write a small sever in the same class but if i call the server nothing is working, if you can help me with that it would be great.